# Use cron job to loop through MySQL table for users

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, cron

I'm kind of new to cron jobs, but I have a database full of users that I would like to post to Twitter too. I've collected all the authorization information I need from them and know how to post to the Twitter accounts, but I need to time it so that each user is posted to every few minutes, similar to a PHP foreach loop but with a time delay between each execution and behind the scenes.

Is there a way for me to set up a cron job so that it grabs a user from my MySQL database, executes the Twitter PHP post script, waits three minutes, then moves to the next user in the MySQL column?

Comment: I smell some spam job.

Comment: Nothing like that, users give explicit read and write access and are informed that a single tweet will be posted to their account before they are authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a PHP script to do it and in the foreach loop add a sleep(xxxx); so it waits each iteration.  then you can cron out the script i suppose.